# How to pass a borrowed string into a an outer scoped Vec in Rust?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'm trying to learn rust hands on while I read the book.
So my program tried to read the SPDisplaysDataType from macOS and the I would like to structure the output of this command somehow (no idea yet how to achieve this, any idea would be welcomed).

Right now I can't seem to compile because of this borrowing error which I can' figure out.

```
use std::process::Command;

fn main() {
    let output = Command::new("system_profiler")
        .arg("SPDisplaysDataType")
        .output()
        .expect("Failed getting display data");

    let display_text = String::from_utf8(output.stdout)
        .expect("Cannot read string from output");    

    let mut gpus: Vec<Vec<&str>> = Vec::new();
    let mut gpu_structure: Vec<&str> = Vec::new();

    for (index, line) in display_text.lines().enumerate() {

        if line.contains("Chipset Model") {
            gpus.push(gpu_structure.clone());

            gpu_structure = Vec::new();
            let mut gpu_title_string = format!("{}", index);

            gpu_title_string.push_str(line);

            let cloned = gpu_title_string.clone();
            gpu_structure.push(cloned.as_str());
            continue;
        }
         gpu_structure.push(line);
    }
}
```

The error I get is:

```
   |
21 |             gpus.push(gpu_structure.clone());
   |                       ------------- borrow later used here
...
29 |             gpu_structure.push(cloned.as_str());
   |                                ^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
30 |             continue;
31 |         }
   |         - `cloned` dropped here while still borrowed
```

Comment: `cloned` is a temporary variable, so its borrow (as the compiler puts it) doesn't live long enough. If you're creating strings in the loop, you need `gpu_structure` to be a `Vec<String>`, and use `gpu_structure.push(cloned)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem looks like you are trying to clone a value in an inner scope, and store a reference to that new value in an outer scope. `gpu_structure` is storing a `&str` (`cloned.as_str()`), but `cloned` is dropped when you exit the `if` statement. Here are some changes, replacing several instances of `&str` with `String` that should work.

```rust
use std::process::Command;

fn main() {
    let output = Command::new("system_profiler")
        .arg("SPDisplaysDataType")
        .output()
        .expect("Failed getting display data");

    let display_text = String::from_utf8(output.stdout)
        .expect("Cannot read string from output");    

    let mut gpus: Vec<Vec<String>> = Vec::new();
    let mut gpu_structure: Vec<String> = Vec::new();

    for (index, line) in display_text.lines().enumerate() {

        if line.contains("Chipset Model") {
            gpus.push(gpu_structure.clone());

            gpu_structure = Vec::new();
            let gpu_title_string = format!("{}{}", index, line);

            gpu_structure.push(gpu_title_string.clone());
            continue;
        }
         gpu_structure.push(line.to_string());
    }
}
```

When using heap-allocated data structures (like `Vec`) and non-static strings, it is typically better to use `String` because they play nicer with the borrow checker, and their ownership is a bit easier to deal with.

Comment: Thank you! that made it work, so if I understand correctly - when I used &str I "borrowed" it but the variable was dropped? and when using String I "moved" ownership to the Vec?

Comment: Yep, it's an easy fix, but just something to keep in mind with most `borrowed value does not live long enough` errors.